# Closing the popup when onclick anywhere but the popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a button that pop ups a window, I did it with a javascript function and I want it to close when I click anywhere but the popup window it self.
I tried doing this but it close up the pop up when I click on the pop up itself
please help!

```css
   

 body{
         overflow-y:scroll;
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
        
        }
        .wrapper{
         width: 960px; margin: 40px auto; text-align: left;
        }
        .popup-position{
         display: none;
         position: fixed;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
        }
        #popup-wrapper{
         width: 500px;
         margin: 70px auto;
         text-align: left;
        }
        #popup-container{
         background-color: #FFF;
         padding: 20px;
         border-radius: 4px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>adfadf</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
      else
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function closePopup(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
      }
      //-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position" onclick="closePopup('popup-box1');">
    <div id="popup-wrapper">
      <div id="popup-container">

        <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">close</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">Open popup box 1</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well you have set `#popup-box1` to close on click...

Comment: i did it just close this when i click anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can put a full width & height overlay div with low opacity behind the popup,

So you can close popup when user click on that div.

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick event inside of #popup-container is bubbling up to your #popup-box1.

Try updating your #popup-wrapper with this onclick.

```
<div id="popup-wrapper" onclick='var event = arguments[0] || window.event; event.stopPropagation();'>
```

Your example with my update below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>adfadf</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
      else
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function closePopup(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if (e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
      }
      //-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="popup-box1" class="popup-position" onclick="closePopup('popup-box1');">
    <div id="popup-wrapper" onclick='var event = arguments[0] || window.event; event.stopPropagation();'>
      <div id="popup-container">
        <p>click me</p>
        <p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">close</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('popup-box1');">Open popup box 1</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I would move this onclick code to your script tag but this should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this ? Because I run your snippet and what I see is not a popup.

```js
(function($) {
  $('.btn-open-modal').on('click', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).addClass('in');
  });

  $('.modal').on('click', function(e) {
    //Check whether click on modal-content
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;

    $(this).removeClass('in');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #808080;
}
.backgroung-deep-blue {
  background: #34495e;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 60em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-content {
  margin: 0;
  font: 1em/1.5em'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  min-height: 120px;
}
/*Button*/

.btn {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0090C0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
/*------End Common CSS-------*/

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  /*Default hide*/
  opacity: 0;
  /*Default transparent*/
  background-color: black;
  /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Background with opacity*/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal.in {
  opacity: 1;
  /*Toggle visible*/
  z-index: 1;
  /*On top*/
}
.modal.in .animated-from-top,
.modal.in .animated-from-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  /*Toggle position*/
}
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 40em;
  margin: 5em auto;
  padding: 2em;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.animated-from-top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-200%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-200%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-200%);
  transform: translateY(-200%);
  /*Default over top*/
}
.animated-from-bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(200%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(200%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(200%);
  -o-transform: translateY(200%);
  transform: translateY(200%);
  /*Default over bottom*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <section class="content">
    <button class="btn btn-open-modal" data-target="#modal-from-top">From Top</button>
    <button class="btn btn-open-modal" data-target="#modal-from-bottom">From Bottom</button>
  </section>
</div>
<!--/wrapper-->
<div class="modal" id="modal-from-top">
  <div class="modal-content animated-from-top">
    <p class="main-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/modal-from-top-->
<div class="modal" id="modal-from-bottom">
  <div class="modal-content animated-from-bottom">
    <p class="main-content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/modal-from-bottom-->
<!-- Orginal Pen: http://codepen.io/trungk18/pen/dXVmEE -->
```

Comment: @ssabin: Do you prefer to have jQuery on your code?
So what you want to archive is just after the popup is open, you must click the outside to hide it ?

Comment: I dont mind having jquery on my code but i just want when i click outside the popup that it will close it